# Camera camera=Camera.open(); Why it is wrong to write separately?

Tags: java, android, camera

```
Camera  camera=Camera.open();  //that's Right,but if you write separately, it's wrong

Camera  camera;
camera=Camera.open();

//reason: Syntax error on token ";", , expected


    Button btn1;
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        boolean sum=true;
        Camera camera; //Syntax error on token ";", , expected
        camera=Camera.open();
        Parameters parameter;
        public void onClick(View V)
        {
            if(sum)
            {               
                camera.startPreview();
                parameter=camera.getParameters();
                parameter.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(parameter);
            }
            else
            {
                //camera.stopPreview();
                parameter=camera.getParameters();
                parameter.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(parameter);
            }
            sum=!sum;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Question is right now unclear as to what you are trying to ask!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a Q&A site that relies on questions that can actually be answered. Please update your question to follow the quality guidelines in [ask], so that it can be reopened and it is clear for other visitors what you are asking. Help us help you by writing clear questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`camera=Camera.open();` is an assignment statement. Statements can only appear inside methods. `camera=Camera.open();` is invalid outside a method for the same reason `System.out.println("Hello");` is invalid outside a method.

`Camera camera;` is a field declaration. They can only appear in classes and outside methods. They're completely different from assignment statements.

`Camera camera = Camera.open();` is a field declaration with a default value. It's still completely different from an assignment statement as far as the language is concerned. It is equivalent to declaring the field as `Camera camera;` and then assigning `camera = Camera.open();` *in the constructor*.

Comment: Not all statements. Declarations are statements. I think what you meant to say was you can only assign variables within methods/constructors, unless you're assigning when you declarate

Comment: @VinceEmigh A static/instance initializer is not a statement. The "statement block" you refer to is officially, and more properly, called "block statement"---and it *is* (syntactically) a statement.

Comment: @WilliamFJameson I realized it soon after, and removed that part. But my point is still true, and saying statements can only appear in methods isn't right. It's not a big deal, just thought it would be a nice fix